# Intellij Idea kotlin cannot auto import some operator function such as +

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

For example:

#### Class `common.number.Number.kt`:

```
operator fun Int.plus(other: BigInteger): BigInteger {
    return BigInteger(this.toString()).add(other)
}
```

#### Class `common.test.Test.kt`:

```
var i = 1 + BigInteger("1")
```

Then the Intellij Idea shows an error in class `Test.kt`.
However, if I add the following import, the error disappears:

```
import common.number.Number.plus
```

How can I make IntelliJ Idea import this operator function automatically?

Answer (score 2):

It is need because you make special extension operator. It is working same like extension function. Import required because idea need to know which exactly extension you want using. So extensions can be more then one.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to get IntelliJ to automatically add the relevant import.

Comment: If it is just for auto adding code then exist special command. Usual using key combination Alt+Enter on problem place.

Comment: @StanleyWintergreen alt+Enter is useless for this problem, it just advise you to create new Int.plus in current kotlin file

Comment: In each file where using extension must be exist import. Besides file with declaration extension. Or i am not understand your problem?

Comment: @StanleyWintergreen my problem is, when I type 1 + BigInteger, I want Intellij can auto import that funtion, rather than i type "import xxx.xxx.xxx" with my hands

Comment: For example. You have two extensions in two files: common.number.Number.plus and common.number.OtherClass.plus. If you do not want see import line in the file, how you think idea will know which extension you want using?

Comment: @StanleyWintergreen just like import a function, if it has lots of, show a list and let me choose. The problem here is, there are nothing, no notice, just like common.number.Number.plus is not exists

Comment: @StanleyWintergreen Maybe you could try my code, then you can find whats the problem I mean

Comment: @wozuiqiangdeaoyi True! I try in idea this case. Sadly but idea not offer my custom extension - "just like common.number.plus is not exists". So for now i have no idea for simplify this case.